# Existence of a minimum of a functional defined on a subspace of a Sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, solution-verification, sobolev-spaces

I consider the functional $J(v) = \int_{a}^{b} \lvert v’(x)\rvert^{2}dx$ defined on

$$
K=\{ v \in H_{0}^{1}(a,b) : \int_{a}^{b} v^2(x)dx = 1 \} 
$$

First we notice that $J(v) = \lVert v\rVert_{H_{0}^{1}(a,b)}^{2}$ where $\lVert . \rVert_{H_{0}^{1}(a,b)}$ is an equivalent norm of $\lVert . \rVert_{H^{1}(a,b)}$.

I want to prove the existence of a minimum : consider $u_n$ a minimizing sequence on $K$ : $\lim_{n\to\infty} J(u_n) = \inf_{v\in K } J(v)$.

**false**We see that $ u_n$ is bounded as a sequence in $L^2(a,b)$ and thus admits a weakly convergent subsequence, denote it’s limit $\bar{u}$.**false**

Taking the constant function equals to $1$ we see by continuity of the $L^2$ norm that $\lVert \bar{u}\rVert_{L^2}^{2}$ equals to $1$

By the Banach Steinhaus theorem we have $\inf_{v\in K } J(v)\leq\lVert \bar{u}\rVert_{H_{0}^{1}(a,b)}^{2}\leq \lim\inf\lVert u_{\phi(n)}\rVert_{H_{0}^{1}(a,b)}^{2}= \inf_{v\in K } J(v)$

Hence the conclusion.

Is this seems correct please ?

### Edit

I think we should use the Rellich theorem that ensures the convergence in $L^2$ of the subsequence and hence that $\lVert \bar{u}\rVert_{L^2} = 1$ so $\bar{u}\in K$.

Comment: No. Weak convergence in $L^2$ does *not* imply $\bar u \in K$. The set $K$ is not convex.

Comment: You are right thank you for your comment. I was thinking of the scalar product helping me but no a square is missing to use a  continuity argument. Have you an idea on how to prove this ?

Comment: You need a compact embedding into $L^2$. Also $J$ is not equal to the $H^1_0$ norm of $v$, but equal to $\| v' \|_{L^1}$.

Comment: Very sorry I forgot a square when defining $J$. I will have to look at this compact embedding notion because I have not seen that in class, I will update the post  after hopefully, thank you !